# MySQL SELECT users OR guests

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
users
    user_id
    username
guests
    guest_id
members
    id
    user_id (foreign key, null)
    guest_id (foreign key, null)
    status
```

I want to get either the user_id and username from users if guest_id in members is null OR guest_id from guests if user_id in members is null.

```
user_id | username | guest_id |
   null | null     | 49       |
      2 | user2    | null     |
   null | null     | 50       |
```

How do I achieve this? The select query should look something like this but I can't get it to work:

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.username, guests.guest_id
FROM users
INNER JOIN guests
INNER JOIN members
ON users.user_id = members.user_id OR guests.guest_id = members.guest_id
WHERE members.status = $status
```

This query returns the correct guest_id but I also get a list of all users:

```
user_id | username | guest_id |
      1 | user1    | 49       |
      2 | user2    | 49       |
      3 | user3    | 49       |
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why not put all users in one table and add a "type" field, which can be "user" or "guest" ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: Yes. Just have one table with a column identifying status. Otherwise, see UNION.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Yeah, I've thought of that too. Seems like it's a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you join the correct tables:

```
SELECT (see below)
FROM members
LEFT JOIN users USING(user_id)
LEFT JOIN guests USING(guest_id)
```

then you decide what you want to show:

```
SELECT 
  IF(user_id IS NULL, guest_id, user_id) id,
  IF(user_id IS NULL, NULL, username) name
FROM ...
```

But your database design seems a little flawed. How would you ever distinct between a user and a guest if they can have the same ID (because in different tables? Re-think what your goal is; in my opinion, a member, a user and a guest are all more or less the same thing: a person with a certain status.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I tested this in both MySQL and also MSSQL, and they seems to behave the same with this.

```
SELECT members.id, users.user_id, users.username, guests.guest_id
FROM members
LEFT JOIN  guests
 ON guests.guest_id = members.guest_id
LEFT JOIN  users
ON users.user_id = members.user_id 
WHERE members.status = $status
```

And i got this result:

```
1   2       TestUser    NULL
2   3       User        NULL
3   NULL    NULL        49
4   NULL    NULL        50
```

Which i guess is what you wanted. How ever, I agree with Bart that your design is i little flawed. What happens if you set a user id and guest id - what will happen?